# No hint path defined for [errors] - Backpack Bulk Action Operation

Tags: laravel, ajax, error-403, laravel-for-backpack

Estoy tratando de crear una operación masiva para mi modelo de Diseño.

Tengo la versión de Backpack `"backpack/crud": "4.0.*",`.

Seguí la documentación para crear una acción masiva sin interfaz [(Backpack)](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-operations#creating-a-new-operation-with-a-bulk-action-no-interface)

Primero creé el archivo que contiene el botón y el script de las acciones masivas:

```js
@if ($crud->hasAccess('bulkPrivate') && $crud->get('list.bulkActions'))
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="bulkPrivateDesigns(this)" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary bulk-button"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i> Hacer privados</a>
@endif

@push('after_scripts')
<script>
  if (typeof bulkPrivateDesigns != 'function') {
    function bulkPrivateDesigns(button) {

      if (typeof crud.checkedItems === 'undefined' || crud.checkedItems.length == 0) {
        new Noty({
          type: "warning",
          text: "<strong>{{ trans('backpack::crud.bulk_no_entries_selected_title') }}</strong><br>{{ trans('backpack::crud.bulk_no_entries_selected_message') }}"
        }).show();

        return;
      }

      var message = "Estás a punto de hacer privados :number diseños, ¿estás seguro?";
      message = message.replace(":number", crud.checkedItems.length);

      // show confirm message
      swal({
        title: "{{ trans('backpack::base.warning') }}",
        text: message,
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: {
          cancel: {
            text: "{{ trans('backpack::crud.cancel') }}",
            value: null,
            visible: true,
            className: "bg-secondary",
            closeModal: true,
          },
          delete: {
            text: "Hacer privados",
            value: true,
            visible: true,
            className: "bg-primary",
          }
        },
      }).then((value) => {
        if (value) {
          var ajax_calls = [];
          var clone_route = "{{ url($crud->route) }}/bulk-private";
          // submit an AJAX delete call
          $.ajax({
            url: clone_route,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              entries: crud.checkedItems
            },
            success: function(result) {
              // Show an alert with the result
              new Noty({
                type: "success",
                text: "<strong>Hacer privado masivo</strong><br>" + crud.checkedItems.length + " diseños han sido puesto como privados"
              }).show();

              crud.checkedItems = [];
              crud.table.ajax.reload();
            },
            error: function(result) {
              console.log(result);
              // Show an alert with the result
              new Noty({
                type: "danger",
                text: "<strong>Hacer privado masivo</strong><br>Uno o más diseños no han podido hacerse privados"
              }).show();
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
@endpush
```

Luego modifiqué el archivo `DesignCrudController.php`:

```js
class DesignCrudController extends CrudController
{
    public function bulkPrivate()
    {
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('create');

        $entries = $this->crud->getRequest()->input('entries');
        
        Design::whereIn('id', $entries)->update(['private' => 1]);

        return $entries;
    }

    protected function setupBulkPrivateRoutes($segment, $routeName, $controller)
    {
        Route::post($segment . '/bulk-private', [
            'as'        => $routeName . '.bulkPrivate',
            'uses'      => $controller . '@bulkPrivate',
            'operation' => 'bulkPrivate',
        ]);
    }

    protected function setupBulkPrivateDefaults()
    {
        $this->crud->allowAccess('bulkPrivate');
        $this->crud->operation('list', function () {
            $this->crud->enableBulkActions();
            $this->crud->addButtonFromView('top', 'bulkPrivateDesigns', 'bulkPrivateDesigns', 'beginning');
        });
    }
}
```

Y es todo, yo esperaría que el `AJAX` funcionara correctamente, pero al momento de ejecutar me sale este error:

```
message: "No hint path defined for [errors]. (View: /Users/Yo/MyProject/resources/views/errors/403.blade.php)"
```

Investigué y parece que fuera un problema en el que no encuentra las vistas de error de Laravel, pero sí existen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté un `php artisan optimize` y `composer dump-autoload`.
Simulé errores para ver que las vistas de error funcionaran correctamente y así fue, todo bien.
El resto de vistas que hay en backpack funcionan bien, pero esta es la primera implementación del proyecto para acciones masivas

Llevo un par de días con este error que, es la primera vez que me lo encuentro, en el tutorial no hay nada de este tipo de error y no he logrado solucionarlo.

Comment: Y si cambias `errors::minimal` a `errors.minimal`? ref https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30226#issuecomment-576289989

Comment: Sí me funcionó, ya no me sale ese error, sin embargo sigo teniendo el error 403, aunque todo admin no tiene accesos restringidos, ni cosas como middlewares especiales

Comment: Comenté la línea $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('create'); de mi bulkPrivate() y ya todo funciona bien :)

Comment: Por favor publica en una respuesta cuál era el problema y cómo lo solucionaste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en los archivos `blade` para cada tipo de error.

Dentro de cada archivo existe una línea que contiene `@extends(errors::minimal)`, solamente reemplazando los dos dobles puntos por un solo punto se solucionó el error,

Para que la línea sea: `@extends(errors.minimal)`